# Azure AD authentication for Azure App Service - is the federated model for Azure AD supported?

Tags: azure, active-directory, federated-identity

We have an Office 365 tenant which uses the [federated identity model](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understanding-Office-365-identity-and-Azure-Active-Directory-06a189e7-5ec6-4af2-94bf-a22ea225a7a9#BK_Federated).

Is such a model compatible with [Azure Active Directory (aad) identity provider authentication](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication/) for a Cordova app which uses an Azure App Service backend?

I would just try it, but I don't expect I will easily get access to the corporate Azure account, and I would like to have some certainty before progressing too far with development on this platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm happy to report that it works. Yay.